# Where can I find Java 8u241?

Tags: java

I am looking for Java 8u241, as it is a requirement for a project I am working on. I have not been able to find it anywhere; not even Java’s own website.

Any suggestions?
I appreciate your’alls help!

Comment: SO is not intended to ask for links to off-site resources, like software updates. Try a search engine or the official Oracle Java website.

Comment: 8u232 seems to be the most recent version (from openjdk), 8u231 is the most recent (from oracle). How can a version that has not been released yet be a requirement?

Comment: Perhaps  you can ask the individual who decided it was required.

Answer (score 1):

Java 8u241 is not available yet. The latest version of Java 8 available from Oracle is Java 8u231 which you can download from https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

Please check https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/release_dates.xml for more details.